# How to handle/wait for the element which is getting displayed only after some operation on the page

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have a requirement where i have to wait for the element for appear after certain operation like clicking on a dropdown. I am automating using protractor and js. Is there any way i can wait or put some condition for the element to be displayed and enabled before performing some operation.

I wrote the below code , but still its giving the error as element not interactable. Sleep however does help in this case. Is there any way i can wait dynamically.?

```
element(by.className("btn-group tropos-sandbox-filters-container")).isPresent().then(function(){
            element(by.className("btn-group tropos-sandbox-filters-container")).click();
            console.log("The dropdown element is present");
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
// dropDownEl: ElementFinder = $('selector');
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dropDownEL), waitingTime, 'errorMsg');
```

as in:

```
const dropDownEl: ElementFinder = element(by.className("btn-group tropos-sandbox-filters-container"));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dropDownEL), waitingTime, 'errorMsg');
dropDownEl.click();
console.log("The dropdown element is present");
```